# Overloaded Bookshelf?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, ps3, technical-issues

It seems I may have inadvertently overloaded a bookshelf in one of my houses, and now I can't open the bookshelf's inventory or read any of the books on it.  Is this a well-known bug?  Is there a good workaround for it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yeah I think this is a bug brought on by the new patch that a lot of people are experiencing. I found this that explains how it happens but unfortunately the only way to fix it is to load a save from before either of these situations (I've bolded the one which seems to match your case):

> - If you select a book on a bookshelf and remove it (rather than activating the bookshelf and removing it from the bookshelf's inventory), the bookshelf becomes inaccessible.
> - **If you're putting books on the bookshelf and you add one more than it can hold, it puts it back in your inventory along with the message that the bookshelf can't hold any more books.** The bookshelf then becomes inaccessible (sometimes the books you were placing on it don't appear, making you lose them books).
>
> **[Source](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/615803-the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim/61231992)**

PC users might be able to fix this using the console but I'm not really experienced with it.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: That's rather disappointing.  The save file from before this condition is long-gone, as I didn't recognize it had happened until *long* after I'd done it.

Comment: That's a shame :( hopefully they will release a patch that might fix this retroactively then. Sorry man!

Comment: Could you add a link to the source? This looks like good information, and it might be helpful for people to be able to read whatever else is available on that page or in that thread, depending on where you found it.

Comment: @DaveDuPlantis Sure thing, added :)